# Positive Zeroes within a Polynomial

Tags: roots

Question:
Let $a,b>0.$ Can the polynomial
$$x^{10} − x^7 + 2x^5 + ax^3 − bx + 1$$

have exactly three (counting multiplicity) positive zeroes? Can it have three simple positive zeroes together with one positive zero of multiplicity two? Explain.

*I understand Decartes' Rule of Signs. There are four sign changes therefore there are a maximum of four positive zeroes that are possible. What I'm not sure is if a zero with a multiplicity of two were to count as two zeroes. For example, $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)^2$, are there five or four zeroes present?*

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: It is not a polynomial ($b^x$)!